# How to filter objects in GeoJson based on an object?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, filter, geojson

I want to filter my GeoJSON data based on an object created based on the selections done in the multi-select dropdown menu.

GeoJSON data

```
    {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
       "type": "Point",
       "coordinates":  [ -115.55783329999998,32.9646667 ]
    },
    "properties": {  "magType":"mb", "type":"earthquake","horizontalError":0.32,"depthError":0.58,    "city":"Brawley",    "state":"California",    "country":"US"}
  },
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
       "type": "Point",
       "coordinates":  [ -115.54583329999998,32.98 ]
    },
    "properties": {   "magType":"mb", "type":"earthquake",    "horizontalError":0.24, "depthError":0.46,    "city":"Brawley",    "state":"California", "country":"US"
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
       "type": "Point",
       "coordinates":  [ -118.13383329999999,33.777333299999995 ]
    },
    "properties": {"magType":"ml","type":"earthquake","horizontalError":0.77,"depthError":0.9, "city":"Brawley","state":"California","country":"US"
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
       "type": "Point",
       "coordinates":  [ -115.555,32.967 ]
    },
    "properties": {"magType":"ml","type":"earthquake",    "horizontalError":0.43,    "depthError":0.67,    "city":"Isangel","state":"Tafea","country":"VU"
  },
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
       "type": "Point",
       "coordinates":  [ -115.55216670000001,32.9658333 ]
    },
    "properties": {"magType":"mw","type":"tsunami", "horizontalError":0.79, "depthError":1.35, "city":"Zaybak", "state":"Badakhshan", "country":"AF"
    }
  },
```

The object of the selected values:

```
sel_data_category = {country:['US','AF'], city: ['Brawley','Zaybak'], magType:['mw']}
sel_data_quant ={horizontalError:[0.68,0.90]}
```

I want to filter data based on these selected values. So the expected output should be -

```
{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
       "type": "Point",
       "coordinates":  [ -115.55216670000001,32.9658333 ]
    },
    "properties": {"magType":"mw","type":"tsunami", "horizontalError":0.79, "depthError":1.35, "city":"Zaybak", "state":"Badakhshan", "country":"AF"
    }
  }
```

Is there any way i could perform this?

EDIT: Missed a horizontalError Value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

**SOLUTION 1: Specific Filter Params**

```js
let arr = [{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-115.55783329999998,32.9646667]},"properties":{"magType":"mb","type":"earthquake","horizontalError":0.32,"depthError":0.58,"city":"Brawley","state":"California","country":"US"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-115.54583329999998,32.98]},"properties":{"magType":"mb","type":"earthquake","horizontalError":0.24,"depthError":0.46,"city":"Brawley","state":"California","country":"US"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-118.13383329999999,33.777333299999995]},"properties":{"magType":"ml","type":"earthquake","horizontalError":0.77,"depthError":0.9,"city":"Brawley","state":"California","country":"US"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-115.555,32.967]},"properties":{"magType":"ml","type":"earthquake","horizontalError":0.43,"depthError":0.67,"city":"Isangel","state":"Tafea","country":"VU"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-115.55216670000001,32.9658333]},"properties":{"magType":"mw","type":"tsunami","horizontalError":0.79,"depthError":1.35,"city":"Zaybak","state":"Badakhshan","country":"AF"}}];

let filterObj = {country:['US','AF'], city: ['Brawley','Zaybak'], magType:['mw']};

let result = arr.filter(o => filterObj.country.includes(o.properties.country) 
                             && filterObj.city.includes(o.properties.city) 
                             && filterObj.magType.includes(o.properties.magType));

console.log(result);
```

**SOLUTION 2: Generic Filter Params (all values in array)**

```js
let arr = [{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-115.55783329999998,32.9646667]},"properties":{"magType":"mb","type":"earthquake","horizontalError":0.32,"depthError":0.58,"city":"Brawley","state":"California","country":"US"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-115.54583329999998,32.98]},"properties":{"magType":"mb","type":"earthquake","horizontalError":0.24,"depthError":0.46,"city":"Brawley","state":"California","country":"US"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-118.13383329999999,33.777333299999995]},"properties":{"magType":"ml","type":"earthquake","horizontalError":0.77,"depthError":0.9,"city":"Brawley","state":"California","country":"US"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-115.555,32.967]},"properties":{"magType":"ml","type":"earthquake","horizontalError":0.43,"depthError":0.67,"city":"Isangel","state":"Tafea","country":"VU"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-115.55216670000001,32.9658333]},"properties":{"magType":"mw","type":"tsunami","horizontalError":0.79,"depthError":1.35,"city":"Zaybak","state":"Badakhshan","country":"AF"}}];

let filterObj = {country:['US','AF'], city: ['Brawley','Zaybak'], magType:['mw']};
let filterObjArray = Object.entries(filterObj);

let result = arr.filter(o => filterObjArray.every(([k,v]) => v.includes(o.properties[k])));

console.log(result);
```

**EDIT**

```js
let arr = [{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-115.55783329999998,32.9646667]},"properties":{"magType":"mb","type":"earthquake","horizontalError":0.32,"depthError":0.58,"city":"Brawley","state":"California","country":"US"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-115.54583329999998,32.98]},"properties":{"magType":"mb","type":"earthquake","horizontalError":0.24,"depthError":0.46,"city":"Brawley","state":"California","country":"US"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-118.13383329999999,33.777333299999995]},"properties":{"magType":"ml","type":"earthquake","horizontalError":0.77,"depthError":0.9,"city":"Brawley","state":"California","country":"US"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-115.555,32.967]},"properties":{"magType":"ml","type":"earthquake","horizontalError":0.43,"depthError":0.67,"city":"Isangel","state":"Tafea","country":"VU"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-115.55216670000001,32.9658333]},"properties":{"magType":"mw","type":"tsunami","horizontalError":0.79,"depthError":1.35,"city":"Zaybak","state":"Badakhshan","country":"AF"}}];

let sel_data_category = {country:['US','AF'], city: ['Brawley','Zaybak'], magType:['mw']}
let sel_data_quant ={horizontalError:[0.68,0.90]}
let filterObjArray = Object.entries(sel_data_category);
let filterQuantArray = Object.entries(sel_data_quant);

let result = arr.filter(o => filterObjArray.every(([k,v]) => v.includes(o.properties[k])) && filterQuantArray.every(([k,[l,h]]) => o.properties[k] >= l && o.properties[k] <= h));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks, Nikhil. Solution 2 worked a charm for me. But I missed the values for HorizontalError which is a range of values selected. Could you please look into it?

Comment: @gkuhu - Do you have the control over `filterObj` i.e. can you group by categories that which needs to be in range or match exact value from array and/or some other filter criteria? Because if you are seeking for **solution 2** then there has to be some generic way of segregating the types

Comment: Yes, I can have two different objects one for the category and one for the ranges but I don't know how to filter data based on these two types of filters. Could you please look into it? I have just made an edit